# SQL Server - Select data from one table based on a string value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am wanting to look up data from one of my database tables based on a varchar stored in another table.

We have a table of `Manufacturers (M)` and a table of `Parameters (P),` and rather than having to have a parameter per Manufacturer (as there is a lot of crossover between 60% of them), we thought it would be cleaner to have parameters per manufacturer where required, and for the other ones just have a set of default parameters.

This means that I cannot store `ManufacturerID` in both tables and create a simple link, instead I need to link using the `ManufacturerName`.

So I need to know if it is possible to Link via `ManufacturerName`, and where there is no match look in the `Parameters` table (P) for Manufacturer 'Default'.

As part of the link, we are also including:

> P.CategoryID = M.CategoryID AND (P.PriceFrom <= M.BasePrice AND
>   P.PriceTo >= M.BasePrice)

Here is the data structures:

> **Manufacturers (M):**
>
> ManufacturerID, ManufacturerName,  CategoryID, BasePrice
>
> **Parameters (P)**
>
> CategoryID, ManufacturerName, PriceFrom, PriceTo, Percentage

Here is some sample data:

**Manufacturers (M):**

```
ManufacturerID | ManufacturerName | CategoryID | BasePrice
3              | Apple            | 1          | 150.00
3              | Apple            | 9          | 99.99
10             | HTC              | 1          | 50.00
15             | Nokia            | 1          | 25.00
19             | Samsung          | 1          | 80.00
```

**Parameters (P):**

```
CategoryID | ManufacturerName | PriceFrom | PriceTo | Percentage | 
1          | Samsung          | 0.00      | 99.99   | 50%        | 
1          | Apple            | 0.00      | 99.99   | 55%        |
1          | Apple            | 100.00    | 149.99  | 45%        | 
9          | Apple            | 0.00      | 99.99   | 65%        |
1          | Default          | 0.00      | 99.99   | 60%        |
```

So we still need to just return 1 result in each link.

Any suggestions of guidance much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the conditions you have posted a `Left Join` should serve the purpose:

```
select M.ManufacturerID, P.ManufacturerName, M.CategoryID
from Manufacturers M
left join Parameters P On P.CategoryID = M.CategoryID AND (P.PriceFrom <= M.BasePrice AND P.PriceTo >= M.BasePrice)
```

Please post your table structure here if I have missed something: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c8e0/2)

Comment: Hi. I cannot see how you are getting around the issue of ManufacturerName Matching or selecting 'Default'

Comment: is my table structure and proposed data correct else please update the same with your's .. i'll update my answer according to that!!

Comment: Hi. Please see updated question, hope this helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

Without a table structure to work with is difficoult but something within the line of

```
SELECT m.name Manufacturer, p.name, p.value, p.Manufacturer alias
FROM   Manufacturers m
       INNER JOIN Parameter p ON (m.name = p.Manufacturer)
UNION ALL
SELECT m.name Manufacturer, p.name, p.value, p.Manufacturer alias
FROM   Manufacturers m
       LEFT JOIN Parameter p on p.Manufacturer = 'default'
WHERE  m.name + p.name not in (SELECT m.name + p.name
                               FROM   Manufacturers m
                                      INNER JOIN Parameter p 
                                            ON (m.name = p.Manufacturer)
                              )
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Can get what you need. The first part get you the linked part, the second part get the default value only for the parameters name that don't have already a match.

This is a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fe6f/6) with a few data and the query

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out this was another situation where I was overthinking the problem.
I managed to get this to work by having the following Select statement nested within another select:

```
(SELECT 
    TOP(1) Percentage 
 FROM 
    Parameters AS P 
 WHERE 
    P.CategoryID = R.CategoryID 
    AND (P.PriceFrom <= M.BasePrice AND P.PriceTo >= M.BasePrice) 
    AND (P.ManufacturerName = M.ManufacturerName OR P.ManufacturerName = 'Default') 
 ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN P.ManufacturerName = 'Default' THEN 'ZZZZZ' ELSE P.ManufacturerName END
 ) AS Markup
```

Many thanks for your help.